# BizTalk 2016 Functoids Not Displaying in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, biztalk, azure-logic-apps, biztalk-2016

I have a quick question.

Currently at my job we are attempting to implement a new project that utilizes Microsoft Logic Apps. Logic Apps implements BizTalk functoids for mapping purposes as anyone that is familiar with Logic Apps already knows. Currently though we are encountering an issue with the BizTalk functoids.

The functoids are not displaying in the toolbox. We tried installing any possible missing packages, we have tried repairing the toolbox and the visual studio ide. We have even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the visual studio ide itself but nothing has made the visual studio functoid controls visible in the toolbox area.

Resetting the toolbox has yielded no results, neither has attempting to use choose items to located the functoid control .dll files either. Is there a step that we are missing, has anyone encountered this issue before, if so how did you resolve it? We are dead in the water until we can load the BizTalk functoid controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't install BizTalk SDK and Logic App EIP SDK on the same box. I ran into this issue as well.

I uninstalled one of the SDKs then I was able see the mapper working correctly.

Comment: Yes, our senior developer resolved this issue by unstalling the BizTalk sdk from his local machine. Thanks for your help.