# Biztalk Mapper crashing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2015, biztalk-mapper, visual-studio-community, vs-community-edition

When I open a .btm file in VS **Community** 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and go to choose "Open Source Schema", VS crashes ("Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working") with this error in Event Log:

```
Application: DevEnv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(IntPtr)
   at     Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.Studio.Utilities.BizTalkProjectHelper.GetService(System.Guid, System.Guid, 

Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.ArtifactBrowser.HierarchyHelpers.GetBtsProjectService(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.ArtifactBrowser.ProjectContainer.InitProject(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierarchy)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.ArtifactBrowser.ProjectContainer.Expand()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.ArtifactBrowser.ABContainerNode.OnExpand()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.ArtifactBrowser.ABTreeView.OnBeforeExpand(System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.TvnExpanding(NMTREEVIEW*)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WmNotify(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

This is where I got the [Biztalk Server 20160 Developer edition ISO](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=biztalk). (I didn't burn a DVD, I just unpacked the ISO and installed)

Has anyone seen this before or have any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps I found to get past this issue:

1. Install [Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015)
2. Install [Biztalk Server 20160 Developer edition ISO](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=biztalk). (I didn't burn a DVD, I just unpacked the ISO using WinRaR and installed)
3. Install [Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53016) **(This is probably what prevented VS from crashing later, but it only seemed to take affect after more than one VS restart)**
4. New Project
5. Select Logic Apps - Integration Account as the template
6. Select a name and OK
7. Under Project, select Add User Control
8. Select Map as the item, and Add
9. Add the schemas to be used to the project.
10. At this point you can select your xsd(s) for the open source schema link, and the open destination schema link. (They are picked from the project, not browsed from disk)
11. Here I could begin map editing, but ran into ["BizTalk 2016 Functoids Not Displaying in Visual Studio 2015"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083127/biztalk-2016-functoids-not-displaying-in-visual-studio-2015) After uninstalling "Microsoft Biztalk*" everything, I had the toolbox working, so it appears that installing Biztalk Server 20160 Developer edition was not only unnecessary, but very unhelpful.
12. So, while I can edit maps, I cannot test them. Testing returns "Custom component invocation failed."
13. I did a re-Install (Repair) of [Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53016) and that fixed "Custom component invocation failed."

Answer (score 0):

I reran the repair tool on the integration tools 3 times and then was able to simply add the map as a new item to the project and the crashing stopped.